# .Net MVC4 and jQuery Mobile changePage or jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I´m trying to bind the changePage function from jQuery Mobile to a Controller/Action with a array of int as a parameter.

The Action is defined like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MessageHistory(int[] ids)
```

If I use jQuery ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MessageHistory",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ ids: messagesIds }),
    success: function (messages) {
        alert('eh!');
    }
});
```

The parameter is well binded and the array isn´t null.

But if I use jQuery Mobile changePage like:

```
$.mobile.changePage("MessageHistory", {
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify({ ids: messageIds })
});
```

The array is null.

Looking for the differences in the request I see that the problem maybe the Content-Type of the request beign made, but I can´t change it in the changePage function.

I also tried with a custom ModelBinder but the value is null too.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found a simple solution that I don´t like very much but solves the problem.

Changed the Action definition to:

```
public ActionResult MessageHistory(string strIds)
```

Also in the Action to convert the string to a int array:

```
int[] ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(strIds);
```

Finally the changePage call to:

```
$.mobile.changePage("MessageHistory", {
    type: "post",
    data: { strIds: JSON.stringify(messages) }
});
```